# Reading CSV file lines with hex content and convert it to decimal

Tags: c++, csv

Here is my CSV file and its contents are in hex.

```
a3 42 fe 9e 89 
a3 43 14 9d cd 
a3 43 1e 02 82 
a3 43 23 bd 85 
a3 43 39 d5 83 
a3 43 3e b9 8d 
a3 43 3f 44 c0 
a3 43 50 c9 49 
a3 43 67 29 c8 
a3 43 67 43 0d
```

I need only the second-last value and the code to extract that value is this.

```
void getvalues(){
        std::ifstream data("mydata1.CSV");
        int row_count =0;
        std::string line;

        while(std::getline(data,line))
        {
            row_count +=1;
            std::stringstream lineStream(line);
            std::string cell;
            int column_count = 0;

            while(std::getline(lineStream,cell,' '))
            {
                column_count+=1;
                if ( column_count == 5){
                  std::cout << std::dec<< cell[0]<< std::endl;
            }
        }
}
```

Since I am reading the lines into a string `cell`, I am unable to do any conversion. At first I tried wrapping the `cell` with an `int` but it returns me the ASCII value of the character which is quite obvious and I shouldn't have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert a string to an integer, you can use std::stoi, which is included in the string package. By default, you can use stoi as such:

```
int num = std::stoi(cell)
```

However since we want to parse a base 16 hex number, then we need to use it like:

```
int num = std::stoi(cell, 0, 16)
```

Quick article about this: https://www.includehelp.com/stl/convert-hex-string-to-integer-using-stoi-function-in-cpp-stl.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that does the job. But I need to get the decimal equivalent of only the second-last value and not the equivalent of the entire row in that column. I tried giving `cell[0]` but `stoi` does not seem to work. It gives out `no matching function for call to stoi`.

Comment: @Koushik Do you include `<string>`  package?

Comment: @OlW Yes I did. @Ryan Kane I could get the two values separately finally. Just passed the `cell[0]` into a string variable and `cell[1]` into another string variable, and converted to decimal using `stoi`.